# Sort a Tkinter optionmenu alphabetically?

Tags: python, sorting, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm trying to make an OptionMenu in Tkinter that lists it's data Alphabetically, but I have no idea how.

This is my code for the OptionMenu data set. (This will expand as I develop the program).

```
data={
'Actually Additions Atomic Reconstructor',
'Advanced Mortars',
'Artisan Worktables',
'Extra Utilities Crusher',
'Extra Utilities Resonator',
'Initial Inventory',
'JEI Hide',
'JEI RemoveAndHide',
'Ore Dictionary Add',
'Ore Dictionary Create',
'Ore Dictionary Remove',
'Seed Drops'
}
```

---

And this is my code for the OptionMenu.

```
var = tkinter.StringVar()
var.set('Advanced Mortars')
p = tkinter.OptionMenu(window, var, *data)
p.config(font='Helvetica 12 bold')
p.pack()
```

Every time I run the code and open the OptionMenu, everything is scrambled randomly. How do I sort this alphabetically?

Comment: does `data` have to be set? sets are unordered. Why not make it a list instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data` is a set, which is an unordered collection in python, the data will always be scrambled. Since `data` already looks sorted, an easy way to fix this is to change `data` to a list, which is an ordered collection:

```
data=[
     'Actually Additions Atomic Reconstructor',
     'Advanced Mortars',
     ...
     ]
```

If your data has to be a set to begin with, you could also sort it beforehand with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
data = sorted(data)
```

Your code runs fine when I run this:

```
from tkinter import *

data={
      'Actually Additions Atomic Reconstructor',
      'Advanced Mortars',
      'Artisan Worktables',
      'Extra Utilities Crusher',
      'Extra Utilities Resonator',
      'Initial Inventory',
      'JEI Hide',
      'JEI RemoveAndHide',
      'Ore Dictionary Add',
      'Ore Dictionary Create',
      'Ore Dictionary Remove',
      'Seed Drops'
     }

data = sorted(data)

master = Tk()

var = StringVar(master)
var.set('Advanced Mortars')
p = OptionMenu(master, var, *data)
p.config(font='Helvetica 12 bold')
p.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @intipablo No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, this solution is fairly simple and intuitive. All you have to do is add in a sorted() when you pass the argument:

```
var = tkinter.StringVar()
var.set('Advanced Mortars')
p = tkinter.OptionMenu(window, var, *sorted(data))
p.config(font='Helvetica 12 bold')
p.pack()
```

Just make sure you put the `sorted()` inside the * splat operator as `sorted()` needs to be applied to a list such as your data variable but with `sorted(*data)`it actually treats `*data` as a bunch of individual variables so `sorted()`won’t work.